# Proof involving Fibonacci number and binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

Question:
Let $F_m$ be the mth Fibonacci number given by $F_1=F_2=1$ and $F_{m+2} = F_m + F_{m+1}$ for all $m\ge1$.

Show that  $\sum_m(C_{n,k})=F_{m+1}$ ;  here the sum is over all pairs of integers $n\ge k\ge0$ with $n+k=m$.

My Approach:
$F_3=2,F_4=3,F_5=5$;

Now for $m=4$: $F_5=5$ and $(n,k)$ for $m=4$ are $(4,0),(3,1),(2,2)$, so $\sum_{n+k=4} C_{n,k}=C_{4,0} + C_{3,1} + C_{2,2} = 1+3+1 = 5 $.

Next how can i proceed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(m) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - 1 - k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right) + \left( \matrix{
  m - 1 - k \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - 1 - k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left( {1\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - 2 - \left( {k - 1} \right) \cr 
  k - 1 \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,m - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - 1 - k \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)}  + \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,m - 2} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  m - 2 - j \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = S(m - 1) + S(m - 2) \cr} 
$$
which is the same recurrence as for Fibonacci Numbers, however
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  S(0) = 1 \hfill \cr 
  S(1) = 1 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
and therefore
$$
S(m) = F_{\,m + 1} \quad \left| {\;0 \le m} \right.
$$

Comment: How S(m) = F(m+1) ?;  I mean why not then S(m) = F(m) ???

Comment: @user9198116 Because the recurrence is the same, **but the starting conditions are different** : $1=S(0)=F(1),\quad 1=S(1)=F(2)$ !